# Infragistics : Grid , how to show html string in column

Tags: model-view-controller, infragistics, iggrid

I'm facing problem in infragistics Grid, i've html string which i'm showing in grid it is showing properly in column BUT i'm facing below two problems

1. Ellipses are not showing.
2. Tooltip is showing html string instead of actual matter/string.
   https://unsee.cc/renamuti/

Comment: Could please provide some short abstract of your code to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Winforms UltraGrid try:

```cs
yourGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellAppearance.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
```

For XamDataGrid try:

```xml
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWpf:SimpleTextBlock}">
     <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
 </Style>
```